# How do I call a variable based on the value of i in the for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, increment

Let's say I have a variable called L0 , L1 , L2 .... L9

How do I make it so that I can call and increment one of these variables based on the value of the integer "i" on this for loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

My idea is to use an if statement or to use a switch, but it would greatly affect the time complexity if I were to call it multiple times.

I tried to make a simple example of what I'm trying to do below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

++(L+i) // (if i = 0 -> ++L0, if i = 1 -> ++L1, etc)

}
```

Comment: You should read about std::vector

Comment: ... or `std::array` if the number of variables is fixed.

Comment: At the bottom of the pages you can see example codes: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Can you explain _"it would greatly affect the time complexity if I were to call it multiple times"_? It doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's any way to accomplish what you're specifically trying to do here, but you could so something similar using an `std::map`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::map<std::string, int> Lvars = {
        {"L0", 5},
        {"L1", 2},
        
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        ++Lvars["L" + std::to_string(i)];
    }
}
```

Another similar method, using pointers.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *L = new int[10]();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ++*(L + i);
    }

    delete[] L;
}
```

Comment: `L[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(L + i)`. `++L[i]` is usually more readable than `++*(L + i)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size at compile time you can use an array:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array L{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

    for (auto &el : L) {
        ++el;
    }

    for (auto &el : L) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1
```

Otherwise you can use a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector L{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    L.emplace_back(20);
    L.emplace_back(30);

    for (auto &el : L) {
        ++el;
    }

    for (auto &el : L) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 21 31
```